# Convert Number type to Date in postgres SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a numeric data in a column `20170930`, need help in converting it into Date in PostgreSQL , tried multiple ways but non seems to work

Comment: The correct solution to your problem is, to change the column's data type to `DATE`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert to a string and then to a date:

```
select column::text::date
```

You can also express this using explicit `cast()` syntax:

```
select cast(cast(20170930 as text) as date)
```

Comment: but when I use `::` in Spring entity manager, it gives me error as `syntax error at : or close to :`

Comment: @abhi . . . `::` is quite valid Postgres syntax and that is what your question is tagged.  I don't know why a particular "framework" would not allow such code.  But you can easily replace it with the equivalent `cast()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the following :

`SELECT cast(yourcol::varchar as date ) as dt1, yourcol::varchar::date as dt2`

where `dt1` and `dt2` values of type `date`, and yourcol is a numeric value such as `20170930`

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=376deaab1169d80807818594a7dda757)</kbd>

Comment: I get this error `ERROR: cannot cast type numeric to date Position: 18`

Comment: excuse me, you're right. I just noticed that your value is of type numeric and needed to be converted to `varchar`(of type text) first @abhi , since you already told that "*I have a **numeric** data in a column 20170930*".

Comment: now I am getting `[22007] ERROR: invalid input syntax for type date: "20170930.000000"`

Comment: I've added the demo. I didn't understand what could be the problem @abhi

Answer (score 0):

Please try below query

```
SELECT to_date(column::varchar,'YYYYMMDD')
```

Answer (score 0):

The best thing is to change column datatype into Date type,

```
  ALTER TABLE table_name
    ADD column_name Date;
```

[image]
As shown above, PostgreSQL supports a full set of SQL date and time types, as shown in the table below. Dates are counted according to the Gregorian calendar. Here, all the types have a resolution of 1 microsecond / 14 digits except date type, whose resolution is day.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody who fell into my pitfall I tried this but my numeric was like a 'seconds past 01-01-1970 format' rather than YYYYMMDD

This worked

```
SELECT to_timestamp(yourcol) as numeric_column_now_date
from yourtable
```

see here
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT